# How to enable a button if validation fails?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a button that is disabled whenever the user clicks on it the first time. This is done to prevent double clicks. The issue that I am facing is: if a required field is left blank, the button will remain disabled. How do I re-enable a button assuming a required field was left blank?

Here's my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" Text="OK" runat="server" Width="70px"
 OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Processing';" 
 UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="Save" TabIndex="11" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the button straight away onclient event write a jquery function and validate the required field value . if it is not blank then disable it or else throw an error.

```
function validate(){ 
       if($('#txtName').val() != '') {
           $('#btnOK').prop('disabled', true); 
        } 
       else {
          $('#btnOK').prop('disabled', false); 
          alert('Please enter Name'); 
        } 
     }
```